# what do I need to start writing in machine language?

Tags: coding-style, machine-code

I  want to start learning the machine language, you know the 0010011 type language. What program if any, can I use to write in machine language? please, I know you guys are going to tell me that "there are better languages out there or why would you want to learn that" kind of comments. I am aware of that so please don't post any of those comments. thanks.

Comment: "Why would you want to learn that?" kind of comments are useful because your reasons for wanting to use machine language (not assembly language?) may suggest different advice.

Comment: I think you mean binary (if you actually intend to write your code in 1's and 0's), not machine language.

Comment: Do you mean Assembly language ?

Comment: Even in the back in the olden days when I programmed machine language, 00010010 would've been 12.

Comment: technically, `00010010` is 18 when converted from binary to decimal ;-)

Comment: Sure, but apparently D Krueger, sensibly enough, used hex rather than decimal. (In the _really_ olden days, way before my time, 000010010 would have been 022).

Comment: @Henning, fantastic, I stand corrected (or at least clarified) =)

Comment: Wha'??!??? Oh, yeah: **octal** :-) Good for you. And God bless the PDP-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bravo! I'm an old-time, long-time ASM programmer and the last one to sneer at your very worthy project. I still know that the Z-80 opcode for CALL is really 0xC9 (or, as you might put it, 1100 1001). In my opinion, you will benefit from the exercise.

I propose, though, that instead of starting with bits you start with assembly code. Then, when you get comfortable, it's a quick shift to machine language. You can do this easily with any version of Visual Studio and, I'd think, with any reasonable IDE.

**EDIT** So sorry: I should have said "any version of Visual Studio that compiles your program into machine code," meaning at least VS for C/C++. I know less than nothing about C#, but I have the impression that the C# compiler emits a translated version of your code in something called "Intermediate Language" (IL). Therefore (as I read it) there's no clean way to include assembly-language source code in a C# source program. There's a discussion of how to call a DLL from a C# program here:

**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/unmanage.aspx**

Your easiest and best bet (maybe your only bet) is to install Visual Studio Express for C/C++ and then to explore the use of the `.asm` directive:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258994%28v=vs.60%29.aspx .**

Stick with the C language; ignore the C++ language for now. You'll have to learn enough C to input, compile, and run a small C-language demo program (by convention and history this is a program called `hello.c` that you can find anyplace). Then you can insert a section of .asm and work with the debugger to experiment with that section.

Yes, I said you'd benefit from the exercise, but I didn't say it would be easy -- it's difficult: you have to learn a lot about what's under the hood. The subject could reasonably be a one-semester course.

But you can do it, with persistence over time. That is precisely where the benefit lies.

Go for it!

Comment: how do I start? you said that any version of visual studio will work, will it work in visual C#? and where do I write my code? can you give me a direction?

Comment: Thanks for the info.I Know that all windows has a VBScript type language built into it, can I use that instead? just wondering, because if I can use VBScript then I can use it in any computer which will mean availability.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that a VBScript-like language won't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't write 00010010.
You need to study assembler for a specific CPU, and then find an assembler for that cpu and if you don't own this cpu - an emulator to run your assembly code against it.

Comment: Compilers are useless when writing machine language.

Comment: @D Krueger: that's an odd thing to say.  A compiler for a high-level language like C# would be useless for machine code.  But don't you still have to have some kind of compiler / interpreter to organize and send the machine code instructions to the processor?

Comment: @jadarnel27, what Krueger means is that the program that translates assembly instructions into actual machine code is called _an assembler_. There is no such thing as an "assembler compiler", and a _compiler_ specifically refers to something that translates a _higher level_ language than assembly code.

Comment: (And to those wondering what _that_ was about, Dani originally wrote "... then find a assembler compiler for that cpu ...", which I have fixed now).

Comment: @Henning Oh dear.  I'm going to keep my comments about machine code to myself from now on haha.  Thank you for the enlightenment, that makes alot more sense now!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Not to mention the fact that you wouldn't assemble, compile, or interpret machine language, since it already *is* machine language. I'm referring to jadarnel27's notion that you have to send machine code through an interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

People don't (usually) write in machine language, they write in assembly mnemonics and have the assembler generate the corresponding machine code. If you really want to write machine language, pick up a developer's manual for your processor such as Intel developer manuals.

If you want to learn using assembly, pick up a book such as Professional Assembly Programming by Wrox. You'll learn when it'd be useful to pick assembly over a higher level language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant assembly language. Get yourself a PSOC board and google for ARM Assembly Language tutorial. Assembly can be really fun once you got used to it but debugging it can be a pain in the butt especially if you have multiple inner loop.